# Generate ip and time limited download link

Tags: php, download

there is a direct link for download a file. users can download that link after payout, like this:

```
http://example.com/download/webapp.rar
```

But I need generate ip and time limited download link to prevent leech the file with others. I want to do this without use any databases. something like this :

```
http://example.com/download.php?a5fds588fgdf
```

or

```
http://example.com/download/a5fds588fgdf
```

is there any tips?

Comment: "Without any databases"? What kind of a requirement is that? You *absolutely* have to store some data to solve this problem, and a database is the best place *by far* to do so. Why on earth are you trying to avoid using a database?

Comment: Without the database, you can achieve this using `cookies` by setting their `expiry`. However, trouble with that is that you can remove the cookies. so this isn't reliable way.

Comment: @GhazanfarMir ...quite apart from the fact that cookies can be spoofed so easily as to make them pretty much useless for this...

Comment: WTF'd so hard over the "no database" thing that I didn't notice the "bind-to-IP' thing. That's a terrible idea. IPs are not fixed, and the address used to pay for the download and the address used to begin the download don't have to match. This is why *nobody does this*. The typical scheme I've noticed is to cap the number of downloads to 5 or something. Minimize "leeching" without totally screwing some of your legit users.

Comment: @meagar I don't want to use DB because my web isn't DB driven.

Comment: accepted answer is flawed. One should never disclose parts used to generate the hash. have a look at TOTP mechanisms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a really good nginx module doing this.

The URL gets two parameters - Let's call them s (security) and t (timestamp). Security is a secure hash generated from timestamp, path and a salt (in your case just add the ip).

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = 'change me cause im not secure';
$path = '/download/webapp.rar';
$timestamp = time() + 3600; // one hour valid
$hash = md5($salt . $ip . $timestamp . $path); // order isn't important at all... just do the same when verifying
$url = "http://mysite.com{$path}?s={$hash}&t={$timestamp}"; // use this as DL url
```

To verify:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$salt = 'change me cause im not secure';
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$hashGiven = $_GET['s'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
$hash = md5($salt . $ip . $timestamp . $path);
if($hashGiven == $hash && $timestamp <= time()) {
    // serve file
} else {
    die('link expired or invalid');
}
```

Now you just need to rewrite the downloads to this "man in the middle"-script and you are done.

Example rewrite for nginx:

```
location /download {
    rewrite ^.*$ /download.php last;
    break;
}
```

I'm not really familar with apache rewrites so you may check for this yourself.

If you are using one of the following modules you do not need to verify all this yourself and it is much better performance-wise but note that it affords more configuration and sometimes another way to generate the url and hash (see module docs here).

Or you just use the nginx secure link module: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureLinkModule

There is also a pendant for lighty: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModSecDownload

Or the nginx secure download module: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureDownload

Maybe there is something for apache too... Maybe you could do something with rewrites there...

Comment: That is an amazing an brilliant way to put it ! Thanks !

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo Thanks mate , can you put my sample link to your script (for my test)

Comment: @NuLLeR I have rewritten my answer to match your example and added some more information what is to take in account.

Comment: It would be possible to use ids and a database etc. yes. Just use it in your logic and use it anywhere the path is used in this example.

Comment: I found I needed to add `$path = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH );` so the hashed path in the receiver script didn't pull in the query vars, and `$timestamp <= time()` should be `$timestamp >= time()`

Comment: `$timestamp <= time()` is correct since you want to invalidate the link on this timestamp not make it valid starting there.

Comment: Disclosing parts of the hash values is a bad practice. You are disclosing the time here. Better use 30 seconds gaps, have a look at TOTP mechanisms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm

Answer (score 6):

If you are not concerned about people being able to decoding some parameters such as IP or timestamp you could try something like this :

```
<?php
$salt = 'SALTING'; // Hash cipher
$key = new stdClass();
$key->limit = time()+3600; // 1 hour limit
$key->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$key->security = sha1(sha1($salt.serialize($key))); // Double sha1 for fun

$key_param = base64_encode(serialize($key));

echo sprintf('http://mysite.com/download/%s', $key_param);
?>
```

Now that's for getting a unique key, valid 1 hour, for ip $key->ip.

To verify it :

```
<?php
$salt = 'SALTING';
$key = $_GET['key'];
$key = base64_decode($key);
$key = unserialize($key);
if($key->security != sha1(sha1($salt.serialize($key)) || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $key->ip) {
    throw new Exception('Security breach. U mad bro ?');
}
?>
```

And you're done :) No database involved. Just hashing and matching hashes afterwards.

But I guess a simple `$_SESSION[$file_id] = time()+3600;` would do the trick in one line...Not as fun though.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, where I must set my file name "webapp.rar" ?

Comment: @NuLLeR Well, where I echo your URL ?

Comment: @Tom - well put! succinctly and straightforward, i wanted to add that my partner and i created (a bit more elaborate, but!) a similar type script... (will remain unmentioned cuz it'd be rude to promote a product here) but we actually jam in a few pieces of information into the $key aforementioned by Tom above.  Adding all sorts of opportunities - like "referer" checking, streaming, (just to name a few ;), etc...  Be also careful of the url limits, as you're eyes widen to the base64 encoding of *virtually* anything in that url :)

Comment: @Tom - also don't forget the time limit check as well on the verification side of things ($key->limit checking...)

Comment: I think the problem with this is, that the hash is valid for all downloads. You need to take the request uri in account so the hash is only valid for a specific file on the server.

Comment: @Tom - This mug has been making the rounds at work: http://i39.tinypic.com/msiyde.jpg

Answer (score 0):

My top piece of advice would be use a database!

But if you absolutely positively have to do it without then I would suggest using a caching library like cache-lite: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.intro.php

Many PHP frameworks (if you are using one) also come with a caching library

You can cache the IP and random key you assign along with an expiry date (some cache libraries will also let you assign the cache validity time)